# Testing my interface in golang with mocks. Specifically test 1 function that calls a sibling function

Tags: go, gomock

Let's say I have this code and I want to create a test for **Foo()**

The important part it **Foo** makes a call to **Bar**

```
package main

type MyInterface interface {
    Foo() error
    Bar() error
}

type MyStruct struct {
}

func NewMyStruct() MyInterface{
    return &MyStruct{}
}

func (m *MyStruct) Foo() error {
    // do something
    m.Bar()
    // do something else
    return nil
}

func (m *MyStruct) Bar() error {
    // do something
    return nil
}
```

Is it possible to create a test for this where I can mock the behaviour of Bar before I run Foo? or am I doing something fundamentally wrong?

I can see that if I extracted Bar into its own service I would mock it that way but that also doesn't feel right.

Any insights or links to documentation would be great.

Comment: You can only mock types, not methods; if you need to mock `Bar` for this test, it needs to be in a separate type. Are you sure you need to mock it?

Comment: This is a very watered-down version of what my project does. I have a service that makes an API call, I want to test this function (Foo) but this function calls a function to create the URL (Bar), this function is also in the same interface.

Comment: Don't mock, make actual calls.

Comment: @Volker Even if the actual call launches missiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to achieve what you need with a couple of changes. First, let me present the code and then I'll walk you through all of the relevant changes.

#### `main.go` file

```golang
package main

type MyInterface interface {
    Foo() error
    Bar() error
}

type MyStruct struct {
    DS MyInterface
}

// here you've to depend upon an interface and return a pointer to a struct
func NewMyStruct(ds MyInterface) *MyStruct {
    return &MyStruct{
        DS: ds,
    }
}

func (m *MyStruct) Foo() error {
    // do something
    m.DS.Bar()
    // do something else
    return nil
}

func (m *MyStruct) Bar() error {
    // do something
    return nil
}

func main() {}
```

Here, I changed a couple of things in order to be able to successfully mock our dependencies. Let me recap them:

1. The `MyStruct` has a dependency of type `MyInterface`
2. The function `NewMyStruct` accepts the interface as parameter and returns a pointer to the `MyStruct` struct
3. In the `Foo` method, we're going to rely on the `DS` field of our pointer receiver type instance

Now, let's switch to the test file.

#### `main_test.go` file

```golang
package main

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/mock"
)

// 1. declare mock
type myStructMock struct {
    mock.Mock
}

// 2. implement the interface
func (m *myStructMock) Foo() error {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

func (m *myStructMock) Bar() error {
    args := m.Called()
    return args.Error(0)
}

func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    // 3. instantiate/setup mock
    myStructMock := new(myStructMock)
    myStructMock.On("Bar").Return(nil).Times(1)

    sut := NewMyStruct(myStructMock)
    err := sut.Foo()

    // 4. check that all expectations were met on the mock
    assert.Nil(t, err)
    assert.True(t, myStructMock.AssertExpectations(t))
}
```

Here, I found it best to add comments within the code to give you a chronological order of what's going on. The idea is that the real system tested (e.g. the `sut` variable) is relying on mock instead of actual implementations. Thanks to the method `Times`, we make sure that the `Bar` method is called once.

I always used this approach when it comes to testing production code and I find it pretty flexible and amazing!
Let me know if this helps you or if you still need something else, thanks!

Comment: thanks, this helps a lot. it took me a bit to understand the composition but I can see why you like this approach. also, does that mean your code instantiation usually looks something like this: 's := NewMyStruct(new(MyStruct))' just curious b/c it does feel a little weird

Comment: Will this still work if `MyStruct` has other fields than the interface parameter?

Comment: Hey @Inian, this will work even if there is another field in the `MyStruct` struct or even if the `MyStruct` implements a method not belonging to the `MyInterface` interface.